# Why helloworld program in OCaml using core package can't print when open Async.Std?

Tags: asynchronous, ocaml

I have this program:

```
open Core.Std
open Async.Std

let () =
  printf "a"
```

Build it with: `corebuild -pkg async,core a.native`

This program can't print "a", but when I change it like this it will:

```
open Async.Std
open Core.Std

let () =
  printf "a"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first program, `printf` is `Async.std.printf`, in the second, it is `Core.Std.printf`.

In the first case you need to launch the Async Scheduler to get the result.

```
  Scheduler.go();;
```

Comment: thanks.add this line under let ()= ? I build it but got an error

Comment: please note that Async.Std & Core.Std are deprecated with recent ocaml. Use Async & Core instead.